# foundation 6.5/SASS Compile 2 css files

Tags: function, sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

I used to compile 2 Css files out of my source (1for the website, one for the RTE/Backend):

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('css'));

  gulp.src('scss/Rte.Default.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('css'));

    return;
});
```

starting width foundation 6.5.1 this does not work anymore, because ZURB changes the whole gulp-script it is encapsulated in sass():

`function sass() {
  ...
}`

unsing gulp-part two timesinsode this function leads to

Error: foundation-sites-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
Exit status 1
    at EventEmitter. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:217:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)

Since I dont really know how the whole gulp-task works (my 6.5.0 attempt was very lucky) I don't know how to solve the compile-task correctly.

Working with 6.4:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths,
      outputStyle: 'compressed' // if css compressed **file size**
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));

    gulp.src('scss/Rte.Default.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths //,
      //outputStyle: 'compressed' // if css compressed **file size**
    })
    .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));

    return;
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function() {
  gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide the full content of the current sass method.

Comment: just added my working 6.4 Script wich fails on 6.5 thank you for any help

Comment: Best solution is probably to create a second task `sass-rte`.